# Is it possible to pass a dynamic variable to process.env, to get the env variable? For example process.env['variable name']

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, environment-variables

I am trying to pass sns topic when creating a message. But depending on the variable that was created, the arn can differ.

So for example in the env variables i will have lets say 3 people and their topics.

```
john = arn:xxxxxxxx
sally= arn:xxxxxxxx
bill= arn:xxxxxxxx
```

Now depending on another logic, it will output var thisvariable="john".

Then I would like to take that variable and pass it into process.env, so it looks something like process.env.thisvariable.

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like with any property of any object in JavaScript you can access them like this, if you know the property name:

```
thing.other.propertyName
```

Or you can access them like this if the property name is calculated or obtained during run-time:

```
const propNameVar = 'myProperty';
thing.other[propNameVar]
```

This would be the same as:

```
thing.other.myProperty;
```

Comment: thank you so much. This solved it. I was putting the propNameVar as as string (dumb i know lol).

Comment: No problem. I think most of us have been there, at least once!